# OpenLayers: value of Event parameter in OpenLayers.Event.triggerEvent

Tags: events, google-maps, openlayers

I'm looking at the
[documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Events-js.html#OpenLayers.Events.triggerEvent)
for triggering events in **OpenLayers**. It lists `triggerEvent` as taking in a `type:String` argument and a `evt:Event` argument. I understand what the `type` parameter is, but what object is the `Event` object? I can't find a clear example.

If it is relevant, I am working on an interface between **Google Maps v3** and **OpenLayers**, and I'm trying to come up with a way so that I can have a the same API interface to calls to:

- `google.maps.event.trigger(instance:Object, eventName:String, var_args:*)`
- `openLayersObj.events.triggerEvent(type:String, evt:Event)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doc is wrong. It should be `Event || object`. Object that will be args passed to the listeners callback.

Look at the source: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Events.js#L820
Example of use: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Map.js#L1042

Comment: fixed in the doc with https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/commit/052be822882ef527dedb82d7d3cc19adc76d6371